# Add value of array elements stored in useState hook React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've a use state hook which holds all amount detail:

```
const [isamount, setAmount] = useState([{
        Amount0: "4455",
        Amount1: "66",
        Amount2: "778",
        Amount3: "34",
        Amount4: "234"
    }])
```

function to store amount values in state array elements

```
var checkAmt = (evt) => {
        // alert(evt.target.name)
            const value = evt.target.value
            setAmount({ ...isamount, [evt.target.name]: value })
    }
```

How can I calculate total of all the amounts stored in the state?

Comment: For what have you this array inside state?

Comment: for adding values from multiple text field

Answer (score 0):

use reduce

```
 Object.values(isamount).reduce((acc, value) => {
    return acc + +value;
 }, 0);
```